# What is difference between tran and transaction in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, transactions

What is difference between `tran` and `transaction` in SQL Server 2005 ?

Following are two statements

```
Begin Tran
Begin
   .........
   .........
End
Rollback
```

OR

```
Begin Transaction
Begin 
   ......
   ......
End
Rollback
```

Comment: @Oded: The purpose of Stackoverflow is to be a repository for questions and answers. It doesn't matter that the answer exists somewhere else in the universe, it needs to be here as well, since this is often where many people look first.

Comment: @Doug - it isn't supposed to be a repository of _all_ questions and answers. In particular those that can be expected to have been given a modicum of research beforehand.

Comment: I disagree @Oded. I typed the question into Google and was directed here. Again, it doesn't matter if the answer is somewhere else. It needs to be here since this is where most people look and are first directed.

Comment: That's kind of circular logic "all questions belong here, because I come here for answers", @Doug

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is no difference. `TRAN` is merely an allowed abbreviation, as can be seen from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx):

> Syntax
>
> ```
> BEGIN { TRAN | TRANSACTION } 
>     [ { transaction_name | @tran_name_variable }
>       [ WITH MARK [ 'description' ] ]
>     ]
> [ ; ]
> ```

The `{ | }` in this syntax description means 'pick one of these two alternatives'

Answer (score 2):

They are synonymous in Transact SQL, it seems that the same logic have been implemented in MDX...

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference, the functionality is the same for both begin tran and begin transaction.

If you were to add BEGIN TRANSACTION (or BEGIN TRAN) before the statement it automatically makes the transaction explicit and holds a lock on the table until the transaction is either committed or rolled back.